# React typescript : Property 'path' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<any, never>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Right now I facing little problem with protected route configuration.
I'm using react-router 5, have installed types and etc.

Error:
*Type '{ path: string; component: () => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<any, never>'.
Property 'path' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<any, never>'.ts(2322)*

App.tsx component:

```
function App(props: any) {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();
    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('Locale')) {
            i18n.changeLanguage(localStorage.getItem('Locale') as string)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" >
                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    </Route>
                    <ProtectedRoute path='/admin' component={AdminLayout} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Suspense>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Protected route component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { logoutUser } from './_Actions/UserActions';
import { Dispatch } from "redux";

class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component<any, any> {

    render() {
        var Component = this.props.component;
        console.log(this.state);
        
        const isAuthenticated = true;
       
        return isAuthenticated ? (
            <Component />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    ...state,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    logOut: () => dispatch(logoutUser()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProtectedRoute);
```

I'm facing this error when I connect Protected route component to Redux. Error appears inside App.tsx on  line.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the type declaration

```
class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component<any, any> {
```

When you wrap this the `connect` HOC, the type becomes

```
ConnectedComponent<typeof ProtectedRoute, Pick<any, never>>
```

So that's the origin of the `Pick<any, never>` in your error.

By using `React.Component<any, any>` you are asserting that `ProtectedRoute` takes props which could be anything.  So when you pass it props with the specific keys `path` and `component`, typescript is telling you that these props don't exist on `ProtectedRoute`

What you need to do is properly define the props of `ProtectedRoute`

```
interface Props {
  path: string;
  component: React.ComponentType<{}> // a class or function component which requires no props
}

class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component<Props> {
```

But it doesn't seem like you're actually using the prop `path`?